# Array of individual elements to return a string sentence

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

I'm creating a program that will decrypt a secret message `'i want a coke!'`. Here is an example of my code so far:

```
class Decoder
  def initialize(coded_message)
    @input = coded_message.downcase.split('')
    @symbols = %w(@ # $ % ^ & *)
    @alph = ('a'..'z').to_a.join
  end
  def decoded_symbol
    @input.map! do |symbols|
      if @symbols.include?(symbols)
       symbols = " "
    else
       symbols = symbols
     end
   end
 end
 def decoded_cipher
  @input.map! do |char|
      if @alph.include?(char)
          char = @alph[@alph.index(char) - 4]
      end
      char = char
    end
 end
 def run
     decoded_cipher
     decoded_symbol
 end
end

Decoder.new("m^aerx%e&gsoi!").run
```

However, this is what the terminal is returning:

```
=> ["i", " ", "w", "a", "n", "t", " ", "a", " ", "c", "o", "k", "e", "!"]
```

I am trying to get this to return as a single sentence. I have been playing with the `run` method to see if I can change the `@input` output, but can't get anything to work. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: `Decoder.new("m^aerx%e&gsoi!").run.join` should work

Comment: `p "m^aerx%e&gsoi!".tr("a-z@#$%^&*", "w-za-v ")`

Comment: @PramodShinde That does work as well. I do want to have it inside the class though. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `decoded_symbol` has no explicit `return` statement, so the array `@input` is used as the return value.

Add one line at the end of the method so that the joined string is returned instead:

```
  def decoded_symbol
    @input.map! do |symbols|
      if @symbols.include?(symbols)
       symbols = " "
    else
       symbols = symbols
     end
   end
   @input.join   # Here
 end
```

Comment: Can I ask why it needs to be put in the `decoded_symbol` method? Why not the `decoded_cipher` or `run` method? BTW, thank you as that gave me exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @TravisSiebenhaar Adding this line at the end of `run` also works, but not `decoded_cipher`. In Ruby, every method has a return value, if no explicit `return` statements are used, then the last expression is used as the return value. So in your original code, the return value of `run` is the return value of `decoded_symbol`. The return value of `decoded_symbol` is the array `@input`.

Comment: Amazing. Perfect explanation. I really appreciate you taking the time to explain it.